# iOS move view above keyboard left black space

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a UIView with a button at the bottom of the view.
I want to move the button right above the keyboard when the keyboard shows / changes height.

The code I am using is:

```
- (void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect keyboardBeginFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBegin = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBeginFrame toView:nil];

    newFrame.origin.y -= (keyboardFrameBegin.origin.y - keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
}
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:) name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

this code works find on iPhone6, but if it is in iPhone 5 and using a Chinese keyboard there will be a black space:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `newFrame.origin.y -= (self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);`?

Comment: ah this caters only for when the keyboard shows, would have to be += if its hiding, maybe your way is better

Comment: @Fonix thanks for replying. My code works in most of the situations just not on iOS 5 with Chinese keyboard.